# I cannot execute a simple function in SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to learn the basics of SQL DB2 and I am stuck trying to use a simple function.

I have generated a small table on which i want to execute my function:

```
create table schema.MyTable (Num1 int, Num2 int)@

insert into schema.MyTable (Num1,Num2)
values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)@

create or replace function schema.trial_funct(One int, Two int)
    return int
    language sql
begin
    declare price int;
    if One < 3 then set price = Two * 2;
    else set price = Two * 3;
    end if;
return price;
end@

select NUM1,NUM2, schema.trial_funct(NUM1,NUM2)
from schema.MyTable @
```

I receive this error when executing the last select command:

> ''The statement was not processed because the function
>   schema.trial_funct resolved to specific function XXXX that is not
>   valid in the context where it is used'' SQL CODE = -390, SQLSTATE =
>   42887

Can anyone help me to fix this? many thanks

Comment: You probably want to use `BEGIN ATOMIC` instead of `BEGIN` in your function body.

Comment: Your code won't compile, until you fix the typo `return int` should be `returns int`. Then your code sample compiles and runs correctly. Are you obfuscating too much?  Always write your Db2-server version/fixpack and platform (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix).

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
create or replace function schema.trial_funct(One int, Two int)
returns int
language sql
return case when One < 3 then Two * 2 else Two * 3 end
```

?